# Problems using position:fixed;

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I have searched through all the similar posts and google and have not quite found an answer so I hope this is not a double post and I apologize if it is.

I am trying to keep my title bar on the top of my page using position fixed. I am not coding for IE right now and am testing with the latest Chrome and Firefox. I know position:fixed is relative to the browser window so the symptoms make sense but I cannot find a cure.

When I add position: fixed; to the header it bunches it up and shoves it in the top right corner and I cannot get it to spread out across the page again, or push the other divs down. am reluctant to use a fixed width because I would like to keep the page as liquid as possible.

I am open to javascript/jquery php or whatever it takes. I also am sure it is a easy fix but I just cannot figure it. CSS below.

```
body {
background-image:url(images/background_image/skyblue.jpg);
min-width:1100px;
padding-left:40px;
padding-right:40px;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
margin:0;
background-color:#022F00;
}

.container {
background-color:#FFF;
padding: 0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;
background-image:url(images/background_image/skyblue.jpg);
background-color:#022F00;
}

.header {
width:inherit;
background-color:ffffcc;
position:fixed;
left:auto;
right:auto;
}

.login {
float:right;
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
}

.rightinfo {
background-color:#33F;
float:left;
height:200px;
width:20%;
border:thin;
-moz-border-radius:1em;
-moz-border-radius:1em;
-webkit-border-radius:1em;
-webkit-border-radius:1em;

}

.contentbackground {
background-image:url(images/background_image/skyblue.jpg);
background-color:#022F00;
float:left;
width:80%;
padding-top:10px;
}
```

I have pictures that I am not allowed to post yet but can email. I hope this makes sense. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not quite. The below answer was a great start though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a full width fixed header try:

```
.header {
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 background-color:ffffcc;
 position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved on of the problems. I have a few follow ups though. How do you make the other divs sit below it until scrolling? I have tried all the different position options and none have seemed to work. Also how do you make it the width of the container? I have a padding on the body of 40px (left and right) and would like to make the header the same. Should I be controlling width another way? Thanks again!

Comment: add a top margin to the container with the same height as the header. So The header covers the margin and all the content is below the header.

Comment: I can only check one I answer I guess. Thank you Jan and Kooilnc.